# Checking if a set of values exists in multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to know better ways of checking if a set of values is a subset of another.

For some reason, I can't make `IN` work so I use something like this approach:

```
-- check if `table1.id` is in other tables
SELECT (
  -- check if all `table1.id` is in table2's `table1_id`
  ARRAY(SELECT id FROM table1) <@ ARRAY(SELECT table1_id FROM table2)
    AND
  -- check if all `table1.id` is in table3's `table1_id`
  ARRAY(SELECT id FROM table1) <@ ARRAY(SELECT table1_id FROM table3)
  -- ...and so on
)
```

So for example, if I have these these two rows on `table1`:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

And these two rows on `table2`:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | table1_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         2 |
+----+-----------+
```

And this one row at `table3`:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | table1_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         2 |
+----+-----------+
```

The result would be `false` because `table3` does not contain both `line_id` of `1` and `2`.

But, if `table3` is like below:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | table1_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         2 |
|  2 |         1 |
+----+-----------+
```

It would return `true`

Is my approach already good? If I use `IN` correctly, would it be faster? Are there some other ways that I am totally missing?

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: Oops wrong column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use inner joins and count the results:

```
with table1_count as (
  select count(*) as count
  FROM table1
),
all_table_count as (
  select count(*) as count
    from (
    select table1.id from table1
    join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id
    join table3 on table1.id = table3.table1_id
  ) sub
)
select table1_count.count = all_table_count.count as ids_everywhere
from all_table_count,table1_count
;
 ids_everywhere
----------------
 f
(1 row)
```

Joining will be much faster than array comparison.

Comment: Looks a bit hack-ish but once you get the logic, it is all good. It actually made my particular query neater than what I have already came up with, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.table1_id = t1.id)
and   exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.table1_id = t1.id)
and   exists (select 1 from table4 t4 where t4.table1_id = t1.id)
```

You can also use exists in a case statement

```
select t1.id, 
       case
         when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.table1_id = t1.id)
           and exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.table1_id = t1.id)
           and exists (select 1 from table4 t4 where t4.table1_id = t1.id)
           then 1
         else 0
       end
from Table1 t1
```

Or list each separate (edit):

```
select t1.id,
       case
           when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.table1_id = t1.id) 
               then 1 else 0
           end as in_tab2,
       case 
           when exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.table1_id = t1.id) 
               then 1 else 0 
           end as in_tab3,
       case 
           when exists (select 1 from table4 t4 where t4.table1_id = t1.id) 
               then 1 else 0 
           end as in_tab4
from table1
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I just want boolean return. Something like my example query. Edit: Or I can just replace with booleans. haha silly

Comment: Looking back into it, I actually haven't paid much attention. I think the logic is a bit different here. It would like check for each value and return something for every value that is in the other tables, right? Mine above would return a single boolean value if a given set of value is found in the multiple tables joined by AND. I was to use the query above to attach something like `AS column_name`.

Comment: My point is that I need only one boolean return. 

For example I just want to check if `[1,2]` is in `[1,2]`, `[1,2,3]` and `[2, 1]`, in which this particular case would return a `true`. But if I check `[1,2]` in `[1,2]`, `[1]` and `[2, 1]`, it would return `false` because the second set doesn't have `2`. 

In your case, it would return some thing like `true`, `true` and `true` for the first example and `true`, `false` and `true` for the second example. I hope that makes it clear somehow. Thanks for taking the time to answer here.